# endless slider with owl carousel script

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I'd like to build an endless slider with owl carousel (http://www.owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/). I have a slider with single item. My Settings:

```
items: 1,
itemsDesktop: [960,1],
singeItem: true,
autoPlay : true,
rewindSpeed : 10,
rewindNav : true,
navigation: true,
pagination: false
```

How can I build it that it start after the last pic without rewind to the first image? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

owl carousel  has updated his plugin and launched 2nd version in this it give us endless loop slider and many more check it out. http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/

By this your problem will resolve.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
   autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
   items : 4,
   rewindNav:false //**Change this property
});
```